# Перескакивает блок div в safari

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Всем привет.Проблема на скрине, меню уходит вниз на Safari. В остальных браузерах все хорошо.
В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код: https://jsfiddle.net/7hr8mf69/

```
    <nav id="nav" class="navbar__nav nav hidden-sm animated fadeInRight hidden-xs">
        <ul class="nav__list">
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="go-to-order btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-two">Главная</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#pricelist" class="go-to-order btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-two">Услуги и цены</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#instagram" class="go-to-order btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-two">Мы в инстаграм</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#contacts" class="go-to-order btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-two">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <button class="toggle_mnu hidden-lg hidden-md"><span class="sandwich"><span class="sw-topper"></span><span class="sw-bottom"></span><span class="sw-footer"></span></span></button>
    <nav class="hidden-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about" class="go-to-order">Главная<span></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pricelist" class="go-to-order">Услуги и цены<span></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#instagram" class="go-to-order">Мы в инстаграм<span></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts" class="go-to-order">Контакты<span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Без html-кода и css вам никто не поможет

Comment: @ИванСопутняк у вас дело в нескольких пикселях, для меню не хватает места и оно уходит в низ.